# Lookup on nested boost multi_index_container

Tags: c++, boost, data-structures, boost-multi-index

Consider following code

```
struct VersionData
{
    VersionData();
    VersionData(VersionData&& rhs);
    int     m_versionId;
    int     m_weight;
    int     m_pId;
    bool    m_hdi;
};

struct VersionId{};

typedef boost::multi_index_container<
    VersionData,
    bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::ordered_non_unique<
            bmi::tag<VersionId>,
            bmi::member<VersionData, int, &VersionData::m_versionId>
        >
    >
> VersionDataContainer;

struct VersionsData
{
    VersionsData();
    VersionsData(VersionsData&& rhs);
    int m_sdGroupId;
    int m_retId;
    VersionDataContainer m_versionData;
};

struct mvKey{};

typedef boost::multi_index_container<
    VersionsData,
    bmi::indexed_by<
    bmi::ordered_unique<
            bmi::tag<mvKey>,
            bmi::composite_key<
                VersionsData,
                bmi::member<VersionsData,int, &VersionsData::m_subdeliveryGroupId>,
                bmi::member<VersionsData,int, &VersionsData::m_retargetingId>
            >
        >
    >
> mvDataContainer;

mvDataContainer m_data;
```

The intention is to lookup using the composite key in mvDataContainer but in some cases I need to lookup in VersionData across all VersionsData. Something like m_data.get<*mvKey*>.equal_range(make_tuple(ignore, ignore, ignore)).get<*VersionId*>.equal_range(123456);
First question, is it achievable?
Second, is this the right approach to use nested multi_index_containers? any performance impacts/gains?

Comment: That doesn't seem possible. Why wouldn't you merge these structs and make a single MIC with multiple indices? That's what MIC is intended for, and that seems to solve your problem.

Comment: @IgorR. Just dropped flat MIC 4 hours ago. It took a long time for lookup and for some odd reason iterating on lookup result ranges. So, I've made it hierarchical to cut the lookup time, after all in flat structure the lookup is slower (IMHO) since it have to search in more elements. Meanwhile I've finished making lookup on nested MIC in for-loop and I observe performance drop. Have a feeling I have to get back to the drawing board with the data structure

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer suggesting a single container for the whole table, here's the idea based on **[Boost Intrusive `multiset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/intrusive/multiset.html)**

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2a8107063dd7494)**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>

// for intrusive multiset
#include <boost/intrusive/set.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;
namespace bi  = boost::intrusive;

struct VersionData : bi::set_base_hook<bi::link_mode<bi::auto_unlink> > {
    VersionData(int versionId, int weight=0, int pId=0, bool hdi=false) : 
        m_versionId(versionId), m_weight(weight), m_pId(pId), m_hdi(hdi) { }

    int     m_versionId;
    int     m_weight;
    int     m_pId;
    bool    m_hdi;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, VersionData const& vd) {
        return os << "{ " << vd.m_versionId << " " << vd.m_weight << " " << vd.m_pId << " " << vd.m_hdi << " }";
    }

    struct ById {
        bool operator()(VersionData const& a, VersionData const& b) const  { return a.m_versionId < b.m_versionId; }
    };
};

typedef bi::multiset<VersionData, bi::constant_time_size<false>, bi::compare<VersionData::ById> > VersionIndex;

typedef boost::multi_index_container<
    VersionData,
    bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::ordered_non_unique<
            bmi::tag<struct VersionId>,
            bmi::member<VersionData, int, &VersionData::m_versionId>
        >
    >
> VersionDataContainer;

struct VersionsData
{
    int m_subdeliveryGroupId;
    int m_retargetingId;

    VersionDataContainer m_versionData;
};

typedef boost::multi_index_container<
    VersionsData,
    bmi::indexed_by<
    bmi::ordered_unique<
            bmi::tag<struct mvKey>,
            bmi::composite_key<
                VersionsData,
                bmi::member<VersionsData,int, &VersionsData::m_subdeliveryGroupId>,
                bmi::member<VersionsData,int, &VersionsData::m_retargetingId>
            >
        >
    >
> mvDataContainer;

void insert(
        mvDataContainer& into, VersionIndex& global_version_index,
        int subdeliveryGroupId, int retargetingId, int
        versionId, int weight, int pId, bool hdi) 
{
    auto& mainIdx = into.get<mvKey>();
    auto insertion = mainIdx.insert(VersionsData { subdeliveryGroupId, retargetingId, VersionDataContainer {} });
    mainIdx.modify(insertion.first, [&](VersionsData& record) {
            auto insertion = record.m_versionData.insert(VersionData { versionId, weight, pId, hdi });
            global_version_index.insert(const_cast<VersionData&>(*insertion.first));
    });
}

int main() {

    VersionIndex global_version_index;
    mvDataContainer table;

    insert(table, global_version_index, 21, 10,                1,  100, 123, false);
    insert(table, global_version_index, 9,  27,                2,  90,  123, false);
    insert(table, global_version_index, 12, 25,                3,  110, 123, true);
    insert(table, global_version_index, 10, 33, /*version 8:*/ 8,  80,  123, false);
    insert(table, global_version_index, 4,  38,                5,  101, 124, false);
    insert(table, global_version_index, 33, 7,                 6,  91,  124, false);
    insert(table, global_version_index, 34, 27,                7,  111, 124, true);
    insert(table, global_version_index, 9,  11, /*version 8:*/ 8,  81,  124, false);
    insert(table, global_version_index, 0,  12,                9,  99,  125, false);
    insert(table, global_version_index, 35, 39, /*version 8:*/ 8,  89,  125, false);
    insert(table, global_version_index, 15, 15,                11, 109, 125, true);
    insert(table, global_version_index, 25, 32, /*version 8:*/ 8,  79,  125, false);

    // debug table output
    assert(table.size()==12);

    // so now you can do:
    std::cout << "---\nQuerying for version id 8:\n";
    for (auto& record : boost::make_iterator_range(global_version_index.equal_range(8)))
        std::cout << record << "\n";

    table.erase(table.find(boost::make_tuple(10,33))); // auto unlinks from global_version_index

    std::cout << "---\nQuerying for version id 8:\n";
    for (auto& record : boost::make_iterator_range(global_version_index.equal_range(8)))
        std::cout << record << "\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
---
Querying for version id 8:
{ 8 80 123 0 }
{ 8 81 124 0 }
{ 8 89 125 0 }
{ 8 79 125 0 }
---
Querying for version id 8:
{ 8 81 124 0 }
{ 8 89 125 0 }
{ 8 79 125 0 }
```

Comment: As always, high quality answers from @sehe :) <br/> I have to read about intrusive containers first.

Comment: ok, got the intrusive stuff. looks good, but how it would be faster than tailored datastructure based on sorted vectors with log(n) complexity in binary search? they claim to be with better locality of data reference, again vector gives excellent locality since it is continuous in memory

Comment: In general, yes. The tailored vectors could never give you distinct indices (as you can not have them sorted in more than 1 direction at once). By all means, make the MIC a flat_multimap already. That still leaves you the question of how to index over that (look at Boost PropertyMap too, IYAM). I think the intrusive hook is close to "tailored datastructure". Depending on your precise access patterns, you _might_ happen to get better performance from a separate vector of pointers to elements. (Profile it! And be very weary of introducing complexity that you cannot prove you need)

Comment: (Also, not you've drifted quite far from your original question)

Answer (score 0):

So indeed, instead of using nested containers, like that (***[live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59dd78ca53bc2286)**)*

You could/should implement it as a single /table/ (after all, this is a table with several indices):

## **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec2991970466763f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

struct VersionRecord {
    int  m_subdeliveryGroupId;
    int  m_retargetingId;
    int  m_versionId;
    int  m_weight;
    int  m_pId;
    bool m_hdi;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, VersionRecord const& record) {
        return os << "{ " << record.m_subdeliveryGroupId << " " << record.m_retargetingId << " "
            << record.m_versionId << " " << record.m_weight << " " << record.m_pId << " " << record.m_hdi << " }";
    }
};

typedef boost::multi_index_container<
    VersionRecord,
    bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::ordered_unique<
            bmi::tag<struct mvKey>,
            bmi::composite_key<
                VersionRecord,
                bmi::member<VersionRecord,int, &VersionRecord::m_subdeliveryGroupId>,
                bmi::member<VersionRecord,int, &VersionRecord::m_retargetingId>
            >
        >,
        bmi::ordered_non_unique<
            bmi::tag<struct VersionId>,
            bmi::member<VersionRecord, int, &VersionRecord::m_versionId>
        >
    >
> VersionTable;

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

int main() {

    auto table = VersionTable { 
        { 21, 10,                1,  100, 123, false },
        { 9,  27,                2,  90,  123, false },
        { 12, 25,                3,  110, 123, true  },
        { 10, 33, /*version 8:*/ 8,  80,  123, false },
        { 4,  38,                5,  101, 124, false },
        { 33, 7,                 6,  91,  124, false },
        { 34, 27,                7,  111, 124, true  },
        { 9,  11, /*version 8:*/ 8,  81,  124, false },
        { 0,  12,                9,  99,  125, false },
        { 35, 39, /*version 8:*/ 8,  89,  125, false },
        { 15, 15,                11, 109, 125, true  },
        { 25, 32, /*version 8:*/ 8,  79,  125, false },
    };

    // debug table output
    assert(table.size()==12);
    for (auto& record : table) std::cout << record << "\n";

    // so now you can do:
    auto& idx = table.get<VersionId>();

    std::cout << "---\nQuerying for version id 8:\n";
    for (auto& record : boost::make_iterator_range(idx.equal_range(8)))
        std::cout << record << "\n";
}
```

Which prints:

```
{ 0 12 9 99 125 0 }
{ 4 38 5 101 124 0 }
{ 9 11 8 81 124 0 }
{ 9 27 2 90 123 0 }
{ 10 33 8 80 123 0 }
{ 12 25 3 110 123 1 }
{ 15 15 11 109 125 1 }
{ 21 10 1 100 123 0 }
{ 25 32 8 79 125 0 }
{ 33 7 6 91 124 0 }
{ 34 27 7 111 124 1 }
{ 35 39 8 89 125 0 }
---
Querying for version id 8:
{ 25 32 8 79 125 0 }
{ 35 39 8 89 125 0 }
{ 10 33 8 80 123 0 }
{ 9 11 8 81 124 0 }
```

Alternatively, you can **[bolt an intrusive container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26835264/85371)** on top of the VersionsData records. This however, complicates the design (you either have to use `auto_unlink` node hooks (sacrificing thread safety control) or you have to make sure the containers are in synch all the time.

Comment: Added Coliru demos, and another answer show-casing the Boost Intrusive `multiset` approach

Comment: Will check the intrusive, not familiar with it. but, you are unnecessarily multiplying the "primary key" - subdeliverygroupid and retargetingid. what if the PK in real life is a little bit more complicated and includes strings? and the number of VersionData under VersionsData can be as big as half million entries? looks like huge memory waste (of which I don't care to some extent) and by using flat struct you make your indices bigger which makes the lookup longer. Correct? In any case I've tested both approaches and looks like they both too slow for me.

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg If they're both slow, what is the test load? Can you make it SSCCE? Anyhow, here's a version with a very expensive `ExpensiveCommonVersion`, that doesn't actually repeat the common data while still behaving like a single table, semantically: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4574bfc8af2e21da)**. _(Note that I disabled locking there, you can even disable the refcounting if you don't mind the common groups to stay around for reuse)_ Notice how the ExpensiveCommonVersion constructor/destructor only runs twice.

Comment: The test load for now - one PK with 120k of versions, we will test it with multiple PKs (should run statistic to figure out number of PKs) and 500k of versions. I will think how I can make it SSCCE, maybe generating random data in runtime or something. In anycase, the flyweight solution looks promising, will give it a try. meanwhile running on tailored datastructure based on vectors, looks like it is order of magnitude faster, but I didn't measure exact time

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg I fully expect flat_multimap to be faster for the outer MIC. I'm not convinced about the index over the versions (that would mostly depend on arch, cache-size and the size of that structure). One key benefit of doing your own binary searches over flat vector storage is that you can postpone the sorting until all data is stable, or avoid sorting at all (relevant when loading large sets of data)

Comment: That exactly what I'm doing - I'm not that concerned with the structure creation time (to some extent), I load all data, sort it, unique it and from this point it is read only and the only thing that matters is lookup and accessing the items. Thanks @sehe, you gave me two interesting approaches with flyweight and intrusive sombined with MIC, will try to implement both of them and see the outcome

Comment: there are surprising results. The outer index on composite key lookup is slower than tailored one (one to three orders of magnitude, depends on the test case), lookup on other indexes are comparable to the tailored DS search. I've put an [example on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/633d89485147d019), which for some reason gets stuck when running the test. Will post results from local machine

Answer (score 0):

It is not the exact answer which I originally asked but since the performance issue was mentioned and in light of discussion with @sehe this is what I found.
1) use flat structure, you can save wasting memory on the same keys using boost::flyweight
2) use MIC instead of tailored containers, MIC might be slightly slower (depends on test scenario) when searching on simple indexes, but once you use composite keys (and implement similar behavior for your tailored datastructure) it is from slightly to significantly faster than tailored DS
My previous statement that tailored one is faster is wrong, since I was using MIC from boost 1.52 and looks like there was a bug when using composite keys with strings (5 orders of magnitude slower than composite without string). When switched to 1.57 everything started to work as expected.

[Tests on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0449dc097ea2148)
Have a nice indexing, guys! :)

Comment: mm. Interesting. Though in fairness `but once you use composite keys (and implement similar behavior for your tailored datastructure) it is from slightly to significantly faster than tailored DS` - I'd say you were doing it wrong <whistle/> It's all about the convenience and lack of wheel-reinvention (so: software stability)

Comment: agree, I hate reinventing wheel, since the wheel providing library doing it for years and it will do it better than I will. Convenience is important too, maybe even is most important (maintainability) but there are obvious and simple cases when tailored DS is convenient enough. This project started as simple enough and when it grew to something more complicated I've switched to MIC, but only after I was sure it can provide expected performance. If MIC wouldn't provide it I would sacrifice convenience and reinvent the wheel