# Trying to learn boost::intrusive Q3 - When storing pointers in ICs, should I use smart_pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, std, intrusive-containers

I have progressed greatly in my understanding of intrusive containers. I have a program that runs for a "while", and then on a line of code like this delete *it; (see below):

```
....

                // :  public list_base_hook< void_pointer< ip::offset_ptr<void> > >
class OneDepthPrice : public list_base_hook<link_mode<auto_unlink>> // This is a derivation hook
{
public:
    Provider provider;
    Price price;
public:
    list_member_hook<link_mode<auto_unlink>> member_hook_; // This is a member hook

    OneDepthPrice(Provider prov, Price p) : provider(prov), price(p) {}
};

...

std::vector<OneDepthPrice *>& vecPrices

for (auto it = vecPrices.begin(); it != vecPrices.end();  ++it)
{
    auto& e = *it;
#if DEBUG
    std::cout << e->provider.name << "\n" << std::flush;
#endif
    if(e->provider.name == newPrices.provider.name)
    {
        delete *it; //This is the offending line in the stack trace in the debugger.

        it = vecPrices.erase(it);
    }
}
```

the program crashes with this stack trace:

```
#0 0x407ddd boost::intrusive::list_node_traits<void*>::set_next(n=@0x7fffffffe2b8: 0x0, 
next=@0x7fffffffe2b0: 0x706860) (/usr/local/include/boost/intrusive/detail/list_node.hpp:64)
#1 0x409189 boost::intrusive::circular_list_algorithms<boost::intrusive::list_node_traits<void*> >::unlink(this_node=@0x7fffffffe2e8: 0x706830) (/usr/local/include/boost/intrusive/circular_list_algorithms.hpp:140)
#2 0x407e2a boost::intrusive::generic_hook<boost::intrusive::get_list_node_algo<void*>, boost::intrusive::default_tag, (boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)2, (boost::intrusive::base_hook_type)1>::unlink(this=0x706830) (/usr/local/include/boost/intrusive/detail/generic_hook.hpp:180)
#3 0x406b5c boost::intrusive::detail::destructor_impl<boost::intrusive::generic_hook<boost::intrusive::get_list_node_algo<void*>, boost::intrusive::default_tag, (boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)2, (boost::intrusive::base_hook_type)1> >(hook=...) (/usr/local/include/boost/intrusive/detail/utilities.hpp:371)
#4 0x405b13 boost::intrusive::generic_hook<boost::intrusive::get_list_node_algo<void*>, boost::intrusive::default_tag, (boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)2, (boost::intrusive::base_hook_type)1>::~generic_hook(this=0x706830, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) (/usr/local/include/boost/intrusive/detail/generic_hook.hpp:160)
#5 0x40534a boost::intrusive::list_base_hook<boost::intrusive::link_mode<(boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)2>, void, void>::~list_base_hook(this=0x706830, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) (/usr/local/include/boost/intrusive/list_hook.hpp:86)
#6 0x405546 OneDepthPrice::~OneDepthPrice(this=0x706830, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) (/home/idf/Documents/TestCPPArrays/TestCPPArrays.cpp:86)
#7 0x403728 UpdateBunchTogether(vectogether=..., vecPrices=..., newPrices=...) (/home/idf/Documents/TestCPPArrays/TestCPPArrays.cpp:291)
#8 0x404765 main() (/home/idf/Documents/TestCPPArrays/TestCPPArrays.cpp:558)
```

This is a strange bug because the program is **not multi-threaded** but it runs for a while without a hitch. I am not sure what is happening, but maybe I need to use smart_pointers?

Comment: Question: why are you using intrusive containers? If you're storing pointers, then by all means, use regular containers.

Comment: sehe, the biggest reason is that I like ICs, i.e., the semantics of not having to worry about all the different places that an object is stored/referenced. I simply delete it from one place, and all the other places are automatically updated.

Comment: I will say this though, I may very well be able to use regular objects and not pointers. I just can't see to get that to work.

Comment: Then you indeed want shared_pointers, or flyweights (with tracking enabled). You do not want Intrusive Containers just for this, because you get into the mess of lifetime management.

Comment: Ok, I was led to this solution by your suggestion in ICs Q1. I also see that they are very high performing which is extremely desirable. I will look into your other suggestions. Do you mean sp+ics? sps don't have ic neat feature that I only have to worry about one place of removing them? Don't know what a flyweight is...

Comment: [Probably] unrelated issue - you do `it = vecPrices.erase(it);` correctly, but then you unconditionally do `++it;`. You want to only increment `it` if you didn't erase... otherwise you could walk past the end of your vector.

Comment: @Barry tada!!!! LMAO - too easy. See above for the fix

Comment: Thanks guys for your expert help.

Comment: @Ivan Your fix isn't quite right, see answer.

Comment: Don't roll answers into question, especially not directly.  The answer can be edited for clarity for your original problem.

Comment: Okay, I've just completed a sample that might inspire you using weak_ptrs. See this recent sample for an applying refcounted Boost Flyweight: ***[in this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825538/lookup-on-nested-boost-multi-index-container/26832795#comment42245382_26832795)***

Comment: Ironically, my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26876194/85371) already contained the correct code to do the predicated erasing iterator loop :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer. When you do:

```
for (auto it = vecPrices.begin(); it != vecPrices.end();  ++it)
{
    auto& e = *it;
    if(e->provider.name == newPrices.provider.name)
    {
        delete *it; //This is the offending line in the stack trace in the debugger.

        it = vecPrices.erase(it);
    }
}
```

You correctly update the iterator when you erase, but then you unconditionally increment it. This is bad for two reasons: you could fail to delete the next object if you need to, and if `erase()` returns `end()` then you just walked past the end of your vector.

To erase safely, you need to do:

```
for (auto it = vecPrices.begin(); it != vecPrices.end();  /* nothing */)
{
    auto& e = *it;
    if(e->provider.name == newPrices.provider.name)
    {
        delete *it; //This is the offending line in the stack trace in the debugger.

        it = vecPrices.erase(it);
    }
    else 
    {
        ++it; // this is where we increment
    }
}
```

Comment: @ivan I would write a custom `erase_remove_if` that operates on a container rather than maintain the above mess of looping and business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Actually with Boost Intrusive you worry about where an object is referenced *all the time* (because references are all over the place).

Maybe you just want weak_ptr. It also looks as though you're trying to implement garbage collection. Here's a slightly reworked idea using weak_ptr:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c50524acf7434461)</kbd>**

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <boost/weak_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using boost::shared_ptr;
using boost::weak_ptr;
using boost::make_shared;

struct Person {
    string name_;
    Person(string name) : name_(move(name)) {}

    using tag = weak_ptr<void>;

    tag track() const { return tracking_tag; }

  private:
    shared_ptr<void> tracking_tag = make_shared<char>('x');
};

template <typename T>
inline bool IsDeleted(weak_ptr<T> const& v) {
    return !v.lock();
}

enum favcolor { red, blue, pink, magenta, beige } favorite_color;

template <typename Map> size_t garbage_collect(Map& map)
{
    size_t collected = 0;
    for (auto it = map.begin(); it!=map.end();)
    {
        if (IsDeleted(it->first))
            ++collected, it = map.erase(it);
        else
            ++it;
    }

    return collected;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Person> people;

    for (auto&& name : { "John", "Mike", "Garbarek", "Milou", "Confucius", "Kiplat" })
        people.emplace_back(name);

    struct Properties {
        favcolor favorite_color;
        struct Car { string brand; int year; } vehicle;
    };

    std::map<Person::tag, Properties> associated {
        { people[0].track(), Properties { magenta, { "Chevy", 1986 } } },
        { people[2].track(), Properties { pink,    { "Kia",   2011 } } },
    };

    for (auto& p : people) std::cout << p.name_ << " "; std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "Defined properties: " << associated.size() << "\n";

    people.erase(std::remove_if(people.begin(), people.end(), [](Person const& p) { return p.name_[1] == 'o'; }), people.end());

    for (auto& p : people) std::cout << p.name_ << " "; std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "Defined properties before garbage collect: " << associated.size() << "\n";

    auto count = garbage_collect(associated);
    std::cout << "Defined properties after garbage collect: " << associated.size() << " (" << count << " collected)\n";
}
```

Output:

```
John Mike Garbarek Milou Confucius Kiplat 
Defined properties: 2
Mike Garbarek Milou Kiplat 
Defined properties before garbage collect: 2
Defined properties after garbage collect: 1 (1 collected)
```